# Como debugar um trecho de codigo na camada model no cake php

Tags: php, cakephp, debug

Preciso debugar um trecho de código que esta no meu model porem quando adiciono debug($varexemplo) ou var_dump ou printf por exemplo ele não exibe nada no navegador! alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

```
public function atualizaCatalogo(){


        $arr_produtos_out = $this->conecta_produtos_atualizacao('ConsultaMercadoriasAIE', 'TipAtlMov', 'E');
        //debug($arr_produtos_out);
        $arr_produtos_in = $this->conecta_produtos_atualizacao('ConsultaMercadoriasAIE', 'TipAtlMov' ,  'I');

    $arr_produtos_altera = $this->conecta_produtos_atualizacao('ConsultaMercadoriasAIE', 'TipAtlMov' ,'A');
    $alterados = array();
    foreach($arr_produtos_altera as $produto_altera){
    $a = $this->atualizaProduto($produto_altera);
    $alterados[$a] = $a;
    }
       // debug($arr_produtos_in);
        ClassRegistry::init('Catalog')->unbindModel(array('hasMany' => array('CatalogTaxon')));
        $catalogs = ClassRegistry::init('Catalog')->find('all', array('order' => 'regional_unit_id'));
        $retirados = array();
        $inseridos = array();
        foreach($catalogs as $catalog){
            //debug($catalog['Catalog']['regional_unit_id']);
            $produtos_out = $this->getProductsInCatalog($catalog['Catalog']['regional_unit_id'], $arr_produtos_out);
            $produtos_in = $this->getProductsInCatalog($catalog['Catalog']['regional_unit_id'], $arr_produtos_in);

            foreach($produtos_out as $p_out){
                $product = $this->procura_produto($p_out);
                $r = $this->retira_product_catalogo($product, $catalog);
                if($r != null){
                    $retirados[] = $r;
                }
            }
            foreach($produtos_in as $p_in){
                $product = $this->procura_produto($p_in);

                $i = $this->insere_product_catalogo($product, $catalog , $p_in);
                if($i != null){
                    $inseridos[] = $i;
                }
            }

        }
        $arr_retorno = array('inseridos' => $inseridos , 'retirados' => $retirados , 'alterados' => $alterados);
        return $arr_retorno;
    }
```

Comment: poderia nos mostrar o código que você tem?

Comment: este é o codigo do model. tem ate alguns trechos comentados que eu estava testando. Na view e no Controller exibe o resultado normalmente do debug

Comment: Quando é assim eu pego a variável que entraria no `var_dump` coloco em uma variável e sessão no controller ou view dou `var_dump` na variável de sessão.

Comment: desculpe pela demora Guilherme, você poderia me dar um exemplo?